# Move mysql server with no downtime

Tags: mysql

I have a small mysql database (200 MB) running on a server. The application using it writes around 100 times/minute and reads a bit less.

I need to move that database to a new server with ideally no downtime or as little as possible. None of the data being written to it can be lost.

Doing a mysqldump then restoring it would take too long i guess, what is the right way to do it?

Most of the tables are using Innodb.

Comment: You should post this to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up replication. Make your new server a slave to the current server. Then switch the master/slave connection (there's enough on the internet about how to do this exactly, but in the end you had 2 servers with almost the same content, one just a tiny bit ahead of the other, and you switch their roles).

Once you've switched them, you can turn off the slave (the old master) and you're fixed.

Comment: +1 - exactly what I would suggest.  Seems like you'll have some downtime while you switch roles and ensure that the replication was caught up, but that should be minimal (less than a minute?)

Comment: You could minimize that to some downtime in writing only, if you make it readonly for a bit -> it can easily catch up then. Another possibility is to make a master-master replication, and then just point to the newer of the two servers for your operations, and wait a bit. But that is tricky to set up

Comment: You'll still need to duplicate the original server. Relatively easy if your filesystem supports snapshots, but otherwise it may be just as hard.